# Replace an element with old_value to new_value in vector - C++

Tags: c++, stl, stdvector

I was going through some legacy code, and found out something that could be improved.
The vector has pointers to a class and all elements are unique in the vector, as per the design.

A function `ReplaceVal` replaces an element having old_value to a new_value in the vector, in the following fashion:

```
iterator i, i_e;
i   = vector->begin();
i_e = vector->end ();
for (; i != i_e; ++i)
{
    if ((*i) == old_child)
        break;
}
// Insertion
    vector->insert_call(new_child, i);

// Since, the pointers are invalidated, do another find for erase
    i   = vector->begin();
    i_e = vector->end ();
    for (; i != i_e; ++i)
    {
        if ((*i) == old_child)
            break;
    }
// Finally, erase the old_value
    vector->erase_call(i);
```

So, essentially, this involves **shifting of elements twice**, *each for insertion and erase*, if you are inserting and erasing elements in the middle of the vector.
For **n insertions and remove calls**, the **complexity is** `O(n*m)`, *if m elements are shifted every time, on an average.*

I think, this can be improved, if I use `std::replace`, as mentioned here @ [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/44hkey01%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) and [std_replace_example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z3h6k5xa%28v=vs.71%29.aspx).

The complexity of the **std::replace** would be `O(n)` comparisons for the old_value and new_value & 1 assignment operation. It'd be as simple as:

```
replace (vector.begin( ), vector.end( ), old_value , new_value);
```

Please correct me, if I am wrong and share feedback on anything that I missed.
P.S. The insert and erase are custom calls, which also update pointers to left_sibling and right_sibling for a given element.

Comment: `replace` would still do more work than necessary, since it would continue searching for another occurance of `old_value`, even after finding the first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't even need to do that:

```
iterator position = std::find( vector->begin() vector->end(), old_child );
if ( position == vector->end() ) {
    throw NoSuchElement();
}
*position = new_child;
```

should do the trick—no erase and no insert.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I didn't think over the easy way, and jumped onto std::replace.

Comment: The semantics of this and `replace` are different if the element isn't present, or if it is present more than once.  (To obtain the exact semantics of the original code, you should append, rather than throw an exception, if the element isn't found.  And probably do something special if `old_child == new_child`.)

Comment: Thanks mate. But such cases are already taken care of. I had presented a simplified view of the situation to get a quick answer.

Answer (score 0):

vector erase returns an iterator pointing to location of the element that followed the  erased

```
iter = myvector->erase(i);
```

then you can use that iterator to insert.

```
myvector->inster(iter, new_value);
```

or the other way around. vector insert returns an iterator pointing to the inserted element

```
iter = myvector->inster(i, new_value);

myvector->erase(iter);
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not use one of these?

- `std::set`
- `std::multiset`
- `std::unordered_set`
- `std::unordered_multiset`

Why you have such complexity? Is there any purpose. May be the `vector` is used somewhere else also, but you may also use *sets* along with vectors for searching.